# UIButton in AnnotationView - How to keep icon and button

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotationview, mapkitannotation

I need help with annotationView. What I'm going to do is to have already added icons, but when Im going to click the pin (icon) I would like to see the button in annotation view frame, as in this pictures:
[image]

After I click it I would like to see this white frame and uibutton:

[image]

The way I found is to add `var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)`
But I cant use this twice - you can see it in my code.

Here is my code:

```
    func znajdzSzczytyNaMapie(_ szczyty: [Szczyt]) {
      for szczyt in szczyty {
        let annotations = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotations.title = szczyt.name
        annotations.subtitle = szczyt.opis
        annotations.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:
          szczyt.lattitude, longitude: szczyt.longtitude)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotations)
      }
    }

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
       // let identifier = "Gora"
       // var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) // The case is that obviously I cannot use let/var annotationView 2x times.
        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        switch annotation.title!! {
            case "Turbacz":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.99, blue: 0.79, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bald")
            case "example":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.80, green: 0.98, blue: 0.73, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bear")
            default:
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.green
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "gora")
   } 
return annotationView
}
```

EDIT:
Now I've got:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard !(annotation is MKUserLocation) else { return nil }
        //let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")
        let identifier = "identifier"
        guard let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView else { return nil }
        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn
        switch annotation.title!! {
            case "Turbacz":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.99, blue: 0.79, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bald")
            case "example":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.80, green: 0.98, blue: 0.73, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bear")
            default:
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor.green
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "gora")
   } 
return annotationView
}
```

but instead of my icons (See first image in this topic) and button, it shows custom annotation pin without button view:

[image]

Comment: Ok. So what's the problem?

Comment: @Desdenova I've updated my post, it wasnt clear, sorry.

Comment: The one you commented out is the correct way to go. Not the manual instantiation. But first you need to register your identifier with `register(_:forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier:)`

Comment: @Desdenova thanks, but when I use the one that I've commented out I get ```Value of type 'MKAnnotationView?' has no member 'glyphImage``` and ```Value of type 'MKAnnotationView?' has no member 'markerTintColor'``` and ```annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn - alue of optional type 'MKAnnotationView?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'rightCalloutAccessoryView' of wrapped base type 'MKAnnotationView'```

Comment: Try adding `as? MKMarkerAnnotationView` after dequeue statement.

Comment: @Desdenova ok, I got you now, so i use it to register more than one annotationview, but how to use it in this case?

Comment: Now I have sth like this: ```let identifier = "identifier"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView
        let btn = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn``` but the case statements still returning ```Value of optional type 'MKMarkerAnnotationView?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'markerTintColor' of wrapped base type 'MKMa....```

Comment: Ok that's another story. Unwrap it with `guard let`. Like `guard let view = ..... as? MKMarkerAnnotationView else { return nil }`

Comment: Ok, now I cant see any errors, but i lost all the icons and now I can see the same as before but with standard red pin, not with my icons like ```case "One":
                annotationView.markerTintColor = UIColor(red: 0.86, green: 0.99, blue: 0.79, alpha: 1.00)
                annotationView.glyphImage = UIImage(named: "bald")``` Also I still cant see the button, just custom annotation title. I think it is because of lack of this ```MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "MyMarker")```

Comment: Can you update the question with all the recent code and new problems so we try to help from there? Tracking the conversation from comments are becoming harder with each comment.

Comment: I've updated my post. See EDIT: section at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code doesn't go beyond this line so it's returning the default annotation view. Also I misled you to the old dequeue method

Instead of this line;

```
guard let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView else { return nil }
```

Try this one, notice the extra `for: annotation` part;

```
guard let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier, for: annotation) as? MKMarkerAnnotationView else { return nil }
```

But for this to work, first you need to register the view before adding the annotations to the map view.

Add the below line of code, before you call `func znajdzSzczytyNaMapie(_ szczyty: [Szczyt])`

```
mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")
```

After you got the hang of how this works, I suggest you to subclass marker annotation view and do your customizations inside that class to clean up code.

Comment: Hi, when I try to add ```mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: "identifier")``` it gets me 6 errors : Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';' ; Expected '(' in argument list of function declaration; Expected '{' in body of function declaration ; Expected 'func' keyword in instance method declaration ; Invalid redeclaration of 'mapView()'

Comment: Sounds like you are putting in wrong place. Try to add it in `viewDidLoad` but before you add the map annotations.

Comment: Yes, I've already did that - now build looks ok, but still I can see only the old annotation view: https://imgur.com/a/9g0k2Bu

Comment: I tried couple of things, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Understant, Thank you !